# App that reacts on the voice of calling party

Tags: iphone, voice, voice-recognition, voice-recording

I need to develop an App that reacts on the voice of the caller - so the participant in the phone call who is 'not there'.. specifically:

Someone calls me and stops speaking. The app should alarm me saying "participant stopped speaking" (it does not matter if the sense of the app seems stupid for you now ;-))

My question is just - is this technically possible? Since apps normally are paused as soon as a phona call comes in. I know they can be restarted during the phone call - but can they react on the voice on the other side of the line or is this only possible for my own voice?

If you think its possible, any special things i have to know?

Thanks a lot!

tim

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Because when any call comes in iPhone our application loose control and it goes in background.

With official SDK it is not possible to intercept any phone calls.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid IDEA using standard SDK, though you can do this using some other IDEA's one of them is CYDIA.

Thanks,